# Use switch access list or switchport trunk allowed?

Tags: switch, vlan

How should I go about preventing a VLAN from accessing another switch, should I use access lists or use switchport trunk allowed except?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want VLAN traffic from a particular VLAN to transit the trunk then don't trunk that VLAN.

Comment: I want all vlans to access it 'except' vlan 10 for example

Comment: Yes, then don't trunk VLAN 10. Presumably you know how to exclude a VLAN from the trunk.

Comment: switchport trunk allowed except 10?

Comment: Should I guess at what brand of switch you're using?

Comment: cisco - all i want to know is should I use access lists or trunk except when denying some vlans from accessing a resource or network?

Comment: I've already said the you shouldn't trunk that VLAN. I don't understand what you're not understanding. If you don't want VLAN 10 traffic to transit the trunk than exclude it from the trunk. If you're using a Cisco switch then the command is: switchport trunk allowed vlan remove 10

Comment: Yea but I want all other vlans to access it?

Comment: All VLAN's are allowed by default. To exclude a VLAN use the command: switchport trunk allowed vlan remove VLAN_ID

Comment: Ok, so when should I use access lists? and doesn't my command do the same thing>

Comment: Use access lists when you want to block a specific type of traffic (HTTP for example) or when you want to block a specific sourde ip address or range or a specific destination ip address or range. I'm not even sure it's possible to block a specific VLAN with an ACL (although it might be). Using an ACL to block a specific VLAN seems like a complicated way of configuring the switch. If I don't want traffic from a specific VLAN to transit the trunk then I don't trunk that VLAN. I don't have to worry about whether or not an ACL is configured correctly.

Comment: Your command would be used if you were specifiying a list of which VLAN's were allowed EXCEPT vlan 10. In your case, since all VLAN's are allowed by default the usual command would be REMOVE.

Comment: RE: `then dont trunk that vlan`.  There are good reasons to trunk all vlans and then remove / except some.  The most common use-case is when you are writing a script, sometimes it's much easier to allow all and then remove the vlan you dont want.  If Cisco was happy with the thought of `then dont trunk that vlan`, then they would not bother including the remove and except commands